# Rewrite to Subdomain from Domain Pointer

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a domain (www.example.com) with a subdomain (test.example.com)

I also have a domain pointer (www.pointer.com) pointing to www.example.com

What I would like to do is have anybody who types in www.pointer.com in the browser view test.example.com

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.pointer.com" />
                    </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="test.example.com" />
                    </rule>
        </rules>
```

but that just sends me to a HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found page

Is there any way to pull this off?

This is running on IIS (windows) with php

Comment: What software is this? I don't recognise that config.

Comment: This is in the web.config file on the server

Comment: Yes, but what server software is running? It's not apache, and doesn't look like tomcat.

Comment: Windows running php.

Comment: I assume so.  It's on the servers at everleap.com

Comment: Then you should probably mention that in your question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I added it

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the action type to Redirect. A rewrite will only invoke a different resource on the server but will not change the URL in the browser. Other than that your rule looks good to me.

Comment: I was using a rewrite because I want the person to see they are still on the pointer.com site.  I know a redirect will work, but that's not what I want.  Is this not possible?

Comment: Is test.example.com a different site? If so it is possible but you will need to use Application Request Routing (ARR) module, see a scenario here: http://nicolas.guelpa.me/blog/2015/02/21/rewrite-redirect-iis.html#rewrite-outside-websites

Comment: the "example" domain is is the A record for the server. The domain pointer is another domain I own.  If this requires installing an app on the server, I don't think that is possible since Everleap (the hosting server) doesn't like doing that, unfortunately.

Comment: ARR is not a separate app but an IIS extension just like the rewrite module itself. I'm not familiar with everleap but from this post it seems like they support ARR http://forum.everleap.com/threads/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites.132/